# React Invalid hook call, not using node, not using jsx

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I've made some other pages without using the hook useState, but now I'm trying to use the hook and I keep getting the Invalid hook call warning. I've tried a number of approaches and changes, but I haven't been able to get it working. I'm just trying to learn how to do it this way, so guidance would be appreciated.

I downloaded react.development.js and react-dom.development.js last night so I'm assuming they're current. Below is the html page:

```
<html>
    <head>
...
        <script src="./react.development.js"></script>
        <script src="./react-dom.development.js"></script>

        <script type="module">
            import AppTest from "./AppTest.js";
            const rootCtr = document.getElementById('root');
            const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(rootCtr);
            window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
                root.render(AppTest());
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The imported module AppTest.js is shown below:

```
export default function AppTest(props) {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setCount(count + 1);
  };

  return React.createElement('div', null, 
    `Count: ${count}`,
    React.createElement('button', { onClick: handleClick }, 'Increment')
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out finally. I'm answering it and leaving it up in case somebody else has a similar problem.

On the load event line in the html page I needed to replace:

```
root.render(AppTest());
```

with

```
root.render(React.createElement(AppTest, null, null));
```